# Azure Storage Client-side encryption: How should we handle encryption key renewal/rotation?

Tags: azure, encryption, certificate, storage, client-side

Azure storage client library has a feature for data encryption using envelope with AES symmetric key and certificate  (store in key vault).

The feature doesnt seem to support key rotation out of box. Is there any recommendation on how should we implement key rotation? Our service is currently using Azure Table storage with client side encryption. And I want to setup automation for on-demand key update (in case certificate is compromised somehow) and regular rotation when certificate expired.

Question

1. For regular expired certificate rotation, the AES key is wrapped and persist in one column of the Azure table. Is it mean that I have to update the whole table when rotating key?
2. If the certificate is compromised which means there is a possibility that AES key is compromised as well. How do we stop current access and update with new key? Do we need to run a separate service to decrypt  and re-encrypt the whole storage?

Thanks,

Duc